Proving that $\epsilon(\lambda) = \epsilon_1(\lambda) + K\epsilon_2(\lambda)$ is a negligible function.
Problem statement
Recall that a function $ \epsilon : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} $ is negligible in $ \lambda $ if for all polynomials $ p(\lambda) > 0 $ there exists a constant $ \lambda_p \in \mathbb{N} $ such that for all $ \lambda > \lambda_p $ it holds that $ \epsilon(\lambda) \leq \frac{1}{p(\lambda)} $.
I want to prove that if $ \epsilon_1 $ and $ \epsilon_2 $ are both negligible in $ \lambda $, then $ \epsilon := \epsilon_1 + K \epsilon_2 $ is also negligible in $ \lambda $, for any constant $ K \in \mathbb{R}_{>0} $.

My attempt
We need to show that $\epsilon(\lambda) = \epsilon_1(\lambda) + K\epsilon_2(\lambda) \leq \frac{1}{p(\lambda)}$, for some polynomial $p(\lambda)  > 0$ and point $\lambda > \lambda_{p}$.
My idea is that I want to try and bound $\epsilon_1$ and $K\epsilon_2$ in such a way that their sum stays below $\frac{1}{p(\lambda)}$. I will do this by splitting $\frac{1}{p(\lambda)}$ into two parts, assigning the two parts to each of the terms. The intention is that the total contribution of the two terms when summing must be less than $\frac{1}{p(\lambda)}$, which proves that $\epsilon(\lambda) = \epsilon_1(\lambda) + K\epsilon_2(\lambda)$ is negligible.
My big question is if I can just split it into two parts, allocating half of the "responsibility" to each negligible function. Let $p_{1}(\lambda) = 2p(\lambda)$ and $p_2(\lambda) = \frac{2p(\lambda)}{K}$.
Then
$$ \epsilon_1(\lambda) \leq \frac{1}{p_1(\lambda)} = \frac{1}{2p(\lambda)} $$
and
$$ \epsilon_2(\lambda) \leq \frac{1}{p_2(\lambda)} = \frac{K}{2p(\lambda)}. $$
Combining the bounds yields
$$ \epsilon(\lambda) = \epsilon_1(\lambda) + K\epsilon_2(\lambda) \leq \frac{1}{2p(\lambda)} + K \cdot \frac{K}{2p(\lambda)} = \frac{1 + K^2}{2p(\lambda)}, \forall \lambda > \max(\lambda_{p_{1}}, \lambda_{p_{2}}). $$
Is this a valid way of proving it?
